# Error converting data type varchar to bigint. MSSQL2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have this error when I run this SQL.

MY ERROR message is :

> ```
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
> ```

```
    SELECT k.hit, 
           k.reach, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), j.signon_date,101) AS dispatch_date, 
           i.name AS agency_name, 
           i.name, 
           a.id, 
           a.pps_id, 
           a.brand_id, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), a.[date],101) AS [date], 
           b.id AS pome_route_detail_id, 
           b.route_id, 
           z.outlet_code as barangay_id, 
           b.reach, 
           l.name AS region_name, 
           e.name AS province_name, 
           d.name AS municipal_name, 
           z.outlet_name AS barangay_name, 
           c.[population], 
           c.household, 
           c._ph_id, 
           z.lattitude AS latitude, 
           z.longtitude AS longitude, 
           f.name AS team_name, 
           f.teamCode, 
           g.name AS brand_name, 
           CASE j.[status] 
               WHEN 1 THEN 'ACTIVE' 
               WHEN 2 THEN 'CLOSED' 
               WHEN 3 THEN 'BASE PREPARATION' 
               WHEN 4 THEN 'CANCELLED' 
               ELSE 'NOT REPORTED' 
           END AS dispatch_status, 
           a.[date] AS formatted_date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 
           k.[start_date],101) AS start_date

           from dbo.pome_route_transaction_detail AS k   


        INNER join dbo.pome_route_transaction AS j ON j.id = k.pome_route_transaction_id 
       and j.status !=4 and k.status = 1    
        INNER join dbo.pome_route AS a on a.id = j.route_id 
        left join dbo.pome_route_details AS b ON a.id = b.route_id and b.[hospital_id] = k.     [pome_hospital_id] 
 INNER JOIN dbo.outlets AS z ON z.outlet_code = k.pome_hospital_id          
               INNER JOIN dbo.barangay AS c ON c.id = z.barangay_id    
               INNER JOIN dbo.municipal AS d ON d.id = c.municipal_id   
               INNER JOIN dbo.province AS e ON e.id = d.province_id   
               INNER JOIN dbo.region AS l ON l.id = e.region_id   
               INNER JOIN dbo.team AS f ON f.id = a.pps_id   
               INNER JOIN dbo.brand AS g ON g.id = a.brand_id   
               INNER JOIN dbo.agency_team AS h ON h.team_id = f.id             
               INNER JOIN dbo.agency AS   i    ON i.id = h.agency_id
```

I included the from clause and the joins. 
The Where Clause is, Where a.[date] = '07/25/2013'
Thanks for the help guys!
i put all the codes here hehehe

Comment: I suggest you try selecting just one column at a time until you find the column that is causing the error. The issue is that you are comparing or concatenating two values of different data types and it is implicitly trying to convert a varchar to a bigint. Without know the data types of the columns we are just guessing.

Comment: What data type is `j.[status]`? if it's a varchar, you need to use quotes around the numbers in your `CASE` statement. But at least isolate the error. It might even be in your `WHERE` clause (which you have not posted)

Comment: Please show the rest of the SQL including the FROM and WHERE clauses which could also be causing the error

Comment: The format of j.signon_date is datetime,null format..

Comment: @user2597863 nobody asked about `j.signon_date` - the only interesting one in the sql shown is `j.[status]`. However, as noted by CodeByMoonlight, it is even more likely that the problem is in the TSQL that you **aren't** showing - the `FROM`, `WHERE`, and any `JOIN` etc

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight,@Marc Gravell. i already put the where and from and the joins.

Comment: @user2597863 - Please help us out - at least identify which column(s) from which table(s) are of type `bigint`. Having to play guessing games isn't much fun.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `select` looks ok-ish. Basically, you need to check each and every one of your conditions - every `where` and every `join`. We can't answer this *for you*, because we don't have the table. For example: your `where` is:

```
Where a.[date] = '07/25/2013'
```

now, if `a.[date]` is actually a `bigint` of the unix-time (milliseconds into epoch), then sure: this would fail.

My best guess based purely on **naming**, would be this one:

```
ON z.outlet_code = k.pome_hospital_id
```

on all the rest, I'm *guessing* (but: you need to check) that each `*_id` is an `int` or `bigint`, so aren't the problem. However, `outlet_code` sounds like something that could be a `varchar`. And indeed, if it has values like `'P20'` then that won't ever work if `pome_hospital_id` is a `bigint`.